# CPU Spikes and Flickering when using 4 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, cpu, gpu

I am setting up a computer for my father-in-law and I'm running into a rather frustrating issue. In short, the computer works perfectly when using 3 monitors but whenever I attach a 4th monitor to the system the screens start flickering on and off, the CPU usage spikes in Task Manager and the system becomes unusable. My father-in-law needs the fourth monitor for his business and it would be great if I could have some instruction on how I can go about fixing the problem.

I've spent significant time trying to narrow down the problem. Here are some specs for the machine:

- GPU: Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050Ti G1Gaming 4GB  (this website explicitly states that the GPU should run 4 monitors: https://multimonitorcomputer.com/best-4-monitor-gaming-video-cards.php)
- CPU: 4x AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processors
- Monitors: 4x Samsung SyncMaster 192N
- RAM: 1x 8GB

I'm attaching the monitors through the 3 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort. The newest GPU drivers are installed.

I'm confused since I wouldn't have thought the CPU would have a tremendous impact on the display capabilities of the machine.  Furthermore, the GPU doesn't seem to experience any increase in heat when I attach the fourth monitor and remains consistently at about ~40C.

Is there anything in particular I should check to help diagnose the problem? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: To further elaborate the system seems to cause the monitors to flicker so long as there are HDMI cables in the three HDMI slots. Each of the monitors is connected using an HDMI/VGA converter. The issue persists when I have the DisplayPort connection removed.